# Проблема записи по адресу

Tags: c, массивы, указатели, динамические-массивы

Имеется следующий код:

```
char *strArr;
int count = 0;

// в функции func(&count, int *p) происходит инициализация и count, и p.
func(&count, p);
/* инициализация массива указателей = массива строк */
strArr = (char**)malloc(count * sizeof(char*));

for (i = 0; i < count; i++){
     strArr[i] = (char*)malloc((p[i] + 1) * sizeof(char));
     memset(strArr[i], 0, (p[i] + 1) * sizeof(char));
     /* код */
}
```

Собственно, из названия темы видно, что когда я компилирую программу, то она вылетает на строчке `memset(strArr[i], 0, (p[i] + 1) * sizeof(char));` 
и пишет **необработанное исключение по адресу ... нарушение прав доступа при записи по адресу**.    Помогите разобраться, в чём дело?

Comment: sizeof(char*) надо писать, у char всего 1 байт, у указателя до 8.

Comment: А еще вы точно объявили `char *strArr;`? если да - то странно, как оно вообще скомпилировалось...

Comment: char *strArr; -> char **strArr;

Comment: Вылетает она не при компиляции, а при попытке выполнения, это первое. Второе: по приведенному коду нельзя сказать в чем именно ошибка, потому что неизвестно чему равно p[i].

Comment: да-да, там опечатка. Конечно `**strArr`.

Comment: в `p[i]` - число от 0 до 10. Занимает 4 байта.

Comment: @Setplus а теперь задумайтесь при каком значении p[i] у вас в memset() будет выход за границу выделенной памяти, при условии, что i = count-1

Comment: @ВладимирМартьянов, что-то пока не улавливаю: ведь я же выделил память под указатель в размере `(p[i] + 1) * sizeof(char)`, столько же и обнуляю...

Comment: @Setplus memset(strArr[i] - заполнение памяти начиная с i-го элемента массива strArr, так что выход за границу тут получается легко и непринужденно.

Comment: @ВладимирМартьянов, как же мне тогда грамотно организовать динамический массив строк, кол-во элементов в котором да и размер самих строк я узнаю в процессе выполнения программы?

Comment: @Setplus разыменование указателей вам поможет.

Comment: В вышеприведенном коде ошибки нет, а вот размер `p` скорее всего меньше `count`, поэтому и валится всё. И да, `x = calloc(p[i], sizeof(char));`